# EmberJS throwing required jQuery version missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a rails app with the ember-rails gem installed it is throwing the following error:

```
Error: assertion failed: Ember Views require jQuery 1.8, 1.9 or 2.0
(in /Users/toverly/Code/tgsoverly/green-zebra/app/assets/javascripts/templates/application.handlebars)
```

I have recently upgraded the ember with the included command in the ember-rails gem, which pulls and compiles the latest emberjs and places it in /vender/assets of the rails app.  I did this because I wanted to incorporate routes, and wanted to make sure I had the newest version.

I have pushed the branch of my project which is on github.

[Code Link to Project](https://github.com/stripedcavern/green-zebra/tree/routes)

What I have done:

1. Manually included the jQuery link to a CDN.
2. Removed the link in the 'application.js' file that loads my app to check the jquery being loading on the page.  It is there and above any ember.js file.
3. Tried 1.8.3 and 1.9.1 of jquery

What am I missing in the rails asset pipeline?  Is there a better way to understand the way ember loads views?  It was working with the previous version of ember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, in order to keep Ember up to date with the gem, you'll want to configure your Gemfile to use the latest Ember-Rails. By default, it will load the latest official versions of Ember and Ember-Data.

Second, your application needs a few changes to be compatible with the latest versions of both. I submitted a pull request with the necessary modifications and some explanation. Hopefully it should clear things up.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I think using the upgraded version of ember-rails was the trick.  I am not sure why my "routes" branch didn't work, but this seems the better solution anyway.